# gtkmm intltool no stock translation

Tags: c++, linux, internationalization, gtk

I'm programming a Linux GUI Application in c++ with gtkmm and the GNU Build System. 
For Internationalization I'm using intltool like it's documented in the gnome tutorial: 
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-internationalization.html.en

The marked strings in my source code are translated,
but the gtk stock widgets like the open button/dialog are no longer translated.

Does intltool get in conflict with the gtk internal translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial says to initialize gettext at the beginning of main. 
But actually you should not do this before calling `Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv)`. 
Then the translation is working as expected, also with the gtk internal translation.